# Сделать синонимами [библиотеки], [библиотека] и [library]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть три метки:

- [библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8) - 393 вопроса, есть описание.
- [библиотека](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0) - 32 вопроса, нет описания.
- [library](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/library) - 140 вопросов, нет описания.

Предлагаю синонимизировать вокруг [библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8), так как у неё есть описание и она на русском языке.

Comment: Сейчас придёт αλεχολυτ и скажет, что ничего не надо удалять, достаточно синонимизировать

Comment: Удалить как мне кажется, бесполезные метки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский конечно не надо удалять. С вероятность 99% её создадут снова в ближайшее же время. Название-то популярное.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это не мне надо писать) Я просто разместил объяву))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну, владельцу мопеда передашь, как увидишь :)

Comment: почему их стало больше?

Comment: @Danis так вроде и изначально их было столько же. Когда вы написали, что их мало, я прям удивился.

Comment: @Зонтик я когда открывал там было 4 и 2. Странно....... Хотя нет, я понял. У меня стояло "цитируемые"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Синонимизировано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8/synonyms) в сторону [библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8)